# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" при обработке AJAX запроса

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте! При получении данных ajax выскакивает окно с ошибкой:

[image: Imgur]

JS часть:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
       $comment = $('#comment').val();
       $id = $('#comment').attr('name');
       if($comment!=''){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'post',   
       url:'file',
       data:{comment:$comment, id:$id},
       dataType:'json',
       error: function(text, error, key, value) {
           alert('Ошибка AJAX: ' + text + ' | ' + error +' | '+ key, + value);
        },
       success: function(data){
           $('#test').prepend(data.author + data.comment + data.date);  
       }
       });
       $('#comment').val('');
       $('.so-hard').removeClass('active');
       } 
   });
```

php часть:

```
if(isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
        $text = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('comment'));
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $author = 'Test';
        $date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
        $this->data_m->add_comment($id,$author,$text,$date);
        echo json_encode(array('author'=>$author, 'comment'=>$text, 'date'=>$date));
}
```

Вчера все нормально работало, сегодня стала выскакивать ошибка, на сколько я помню, в коде ничего не менял! Данные добавляются в базу нормально, но вот вставить данные на страницу не удается, видимо из-за этой ошибки. В Firefox в всплывающем окне выдает

> Ошибка AJAX: [object Object] | parsererror | SyntaxError: JSON.parse:
>   unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data.

Посмотрел ответ с сервера, такая вот строка в самом верху страницы: `{"author":"Test","text":"hfghfgh","date":"18-01-2014 23:29"}`

Comment: вы html вместо json получаете, скорее всего это ошибка 500, смотрите в дебагере что именно приходит к вам через запрос.

Comment: Alexey123, вот что получил:
http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=9271c646c40907064e2c7acb35d805fb

Comment: Уже понятнее. Файл 'file' к которому обращается AJAX не заканчивает выполняться на выводе JSON данных. Видимо ниже приведенного кода php есть еще какой-то код, который посылает в догонку еще и чуть ли не полную страницу сайта, которую как раз видно на вашем скриншоте после JSON данных.

Comment: Alexey, вот код 'file' http://pastebin.com/utma1Wj1 теперь код добавления данных идет в низу файла, а до этого в низу был вывод вида! Но приходящий результат не изменился! Так же вся страница выскакивает

Comment: C CodeIgniter не работал, поэтому остальное предположения. Мне непонятно зачем там нужен вывод представления view, насколько я понимаю он ничего менять не должен. Тогда то при выполнении такого php кода: [http://pastebin.com/H5ec9M8f](http://pastebin.com/H5ec9M8f) ошибка сохранится. Если это так, то видимо в приложение менялись какие-то другие файлы(htaccess, настройки, код других контроллеров и т.п.) и они повлияли потом на саму работу фреймворка и приложения. Тогда придется анализировать полностью приложение, а не только приведенные исходники и искать, в какой момент что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Alexey123, я сделал добавление комментария в отдельном методе, все нормально теперь, приходят запрашиваемые данные а не вся страница. Файл file отвечает за вывод конкретного файла из каталога, если ты понял о чем я, так что там без вида не как! Спрошу еще, не отходя от кассы) когда вставляю данные на страницу в блок $('#test').prepend(data.author, data.text, data.date); данные отображаются, но если посмотреть исходный код страницы, то там нет вставленных данных, как это исправить? Как сделать, что бы данные появлялись в исходном коде?

Comment: Да, я понял. Во фреймворках обычно делается разбиение по типу контента, который должен быть отправлен обратно. Можно поискать данную тему по запросам "codeigniter ajax pagination", что бы не делать еще один метод контроллера. А по поводу исходного кода - это сделано специально и этого не отменить. Нужно, что бы: 1. пользователь смог посмотреть, что ему пришло изначально без модификаций; 2.сохранить исходную страницу в первозданном виде, не исковерканную скриптом и начать выполнение сначала. 3. Если интересен уже модифицированный код, его DOM-дерево можно посмотреть в консолях браузера.

Comment: благодарю за ответы, ты знаешь как можно сделать, что бы обновления происходили в фоновом режиме? Например, кто то поставил лайк и это видят все пользователи, в общем как вконтакте сделано. Хотелось бы знать, в какую сторону копать по этому вопросу

Answer (score 5):

Вообще эта ошибка говорит о том, что в ответе приходит строка с недопустимым для JSON синтаксисом, то есть какой-то "<" встречается и его можно не увидеть при добавление на саму страницу, если это тег. Что бы удостоверится в правильности ответа сделайте так: в javascript убираете строку

```
dataType:'json',
```

и в функцию `success` добавляете вывод данных:

```
success: function(data){ alert(data); }
```

и смотрите, что будет выведено.